# Extend the limit of Memory allocated to R using Sever

Tags: r, memory, server, allocation

I am running a species distribution model using R in a server. I am saving all my R environment, however when I try to visualize and plot the objects saved I get an error "Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(fn, "rb") : cannot open file '/localscratch/anandam.9761522.0/RtmpnCnH0y/raster/r_tmp_2020-07-13_195526_260024_04625.gri': No such file or directory".
It seems that some important information was saved in a temporary directory and I cannot access it after the analysis is done. Is that right?

One possible solution seems to use the raster::readAll (Read all values from a raster file associated with a Raster* object into memory). However, when I use this, I am getting "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 12.5Gb". I tried to extend the limit of Memory allocated to R in the cluster, but it seems the memory does not change. When I do the same using my MacBook Pro it works using memory_limit{ulimit}. Is there another way to increase the memory used in R for linux OS? Or, is there another way to save all my R objects without using a temporary directory, so I can recover everything after the analysis is finished?

```
#LIST the tif files with selected predictors
    predictors1 <- list.files(path="/home/.../predictors_test",pattern =".tif", full.names = TRUE)
    
#RASTER the objects from the list
    predictors2 <- lapply(predictors1, raster)
    
#STACK predictors
    Predictors <- stack(predictors2)
    
#Save all the information of Predictors raster object
    Predictors <- readAll(Predictors)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are "saving all my R environment" --- That is a nice shortcut, that generally  works, although I think it is almost always a bad idea. Things are much clearer if instead you explicitly save the data you need to keep in files; and read them again as needed. In most cases you can use saveRDS/readRDS.

You cannot use saveRDS for Raster* objects that point to a file in the temp folder. All you would be saving is an object that points to a file that disappeared when your session ended (and that is why saving sessions does not work either).

The best approach is to avoid these temp files by using the `filename=` argument that most functions in the raster package provide; or at least for the last processing step. Alternatively, you can use `writeRaster` to save what you want to keep after you are done processing.